# No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl -- not true but why does development mode think it is

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

Every time I try to bring up an application in Development mode in Eclipse I get this message and that's as far as it goes:

[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl

My web.xml includes:

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>FERPASigningRequest.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And, I do have the -startupUrl set in the run configuration for the app in Eclipse.

I'm confused.

~ Rob

Answer (score 0):

> How to set a configuration in Eclipse GWT

Simply select any **Web Application** and click on **RED X** icon displayed on top right of it to remove an existing configuration.

Once a Web Application is configured then there is no need to create it again. Just **launch it from existing one** to avoid this issue by choosing a launch configuration again.

Once configured then **don't** run it again by RIGHT click on the project to run as Web Application. Simply select from the existing one form the tool bar as shown in below screenshots.

Look at the `-startupUrl` in Program arguments in below screenshot.

[image]

[image]